# Passing objects in CoreData

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using CoreData in my application and it is a one-to-many relationship, I have two entities called `folders` and `files`. So a folder can have many files. So my first view controller shows all folders and when clicked on each folder, I show the files present in it.

Now all the folders and files present in it are created by user dynamically and are not coming from any database or from web server.

Now I have one more view controller, which I open from app delegate, and here I want to show some files.

I know that first we should pass the `managedObjectContext`, which will be declared in app delegate

```
ViewController *View = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName: @"ViewController" bundle:nil]
View.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

So if we just pass `managedObjectContext`, can we access the file entity objects, OR we have to pass file entity object also.

Now as you know, I have two entities, called `Folder` and `File`, now to access files stored in any folder, I just do this.

```
NSMutableArray *filesArray = [self.folder.file mutableCopy];
```

But now, I want to show the files in anyView I want, which can be opened after two three navigations or it is opened directly from appDelegate.m.

To be very clear , my question is how to do this? i.e how can I get filesArray from `AppDelegate`.

Based on Below Answer edited. I have created a fetchResultsController this way

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (m_fetchResultsController != nil) {
        return m_fetchResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"alarm" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"alarm!= nil"]];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    
    return  m_fetchResultsController;   
}
```

and in ViewDidLoad and I written this way

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }


     NSMutableArray *alarms = [[self.fetchResultsController fetchedObjects]mutableCopy];

    NSLog(@"alarmsCount:%d",[alarms count]);
}
```

Regards
Ranjit.

Comment: Edit your question and write your doubt ;)

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170772/move-rows-to-bottom-in-a-tableview-which-uses-coredata

Comment: Hi, now I'm a bit busy. I will read your question as soon as possible.

Comment: @flexaddicted, as you told me how to get the all the files irrespective of which folder it belongs. So now after doing that can I know to which folder it belongs. suppose I have two files A and B, from different folders in a separate view controller, can I know whether  A belongs to which folder.

Comment: @flexaddicted , As you said in your below answer, that if you have many files it is better to use NSFetchResultsController.File enitity contains a property called reminder which is of NSDate type. Actually to few files I set reminders, and I dont want all the files, I just want the files which I have set reminders. because, if I access all the files here, it will become slow.How to do this. My second question is that, can we get to know to which folder the files belong from this View.

Comment: I suggest you to open a new question explaining this. It's quite complicated to say in a comment or chat. About the reminder it's quite simple but for the other one you should provide other info. Thanks.

Comment: @flexaddicted, already opened http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170772/move-rows-to-bottom-in-a-tableview-which-uses-coredata. How to go about reminders

Comment: @flexaddicted, please check the question, I have edited it. let me know whether I am correct. And why just the sort descriptor doesnt return the only files with reminder set. and second question what about my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170772/move-rows-to-bottom-in-a-tableview-which-uses-coredata

Comment: @flexaddicted, please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170772/move-rows-to-bottom-in-a-tableview-which-uses-coredata

Comment: @flexaddicted, I want to chat with you, please reply

Comment: You should ask another question for the second part of this question (the edited part). Questions should contains only one argument. And remember that I cannot provide a full detailed answer for your question. I provided a lot of hints for you. Use a singleton class to achieve your goal is enough. So please, check your own. Thank you.

Comment: @flexaddicted, I didnt get you, and about which question are you talking about.

Comment: I provided an answer for your other question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @flexaddicted, please check the updated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170772/move-rows-to-bottom-in-a-tableview-which-uses-coredata

Comment: Hi @flexaddicted, please tell me once again how to find the folder to which the file belongs too, Your answer is missing from my question.

Comment: Hi @flexaddicted, look at this, https://github.com/homeyer/CustomUIActionSheet#readme

Comment: I have few doubts regarding this code, can we chat?

Comment: Hi @flexaddicted, I want to use check a bool property whether it is true in a particular entity ,for that I did this way[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"completedStatus = 1 IN %@", folder.file]];But I get error.Can you tell me where I am goin wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you share more details we could help you, but in the meantime...

If the master controller shows the folder and the details controller show the files, simply inject a reference of the selected folder to the detail controller.

For example, create a property in the detail controller like this (it is needed to be synthesized)

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) Folders* currentFolder;
```

When you create a detail controller, do the following

```
DetailController* detCtr = // alloc-init here
detCtr.currentFolder = // the folder you want to pass in
```

*Some Notes*

Use Camel Case notation.
Use `NSFetchedResultsController` for lazy loading data in association with tables, etc.
Rename entity `Files` and `Folders` in their singular form.

**Edit**

Ok, so if you want to access your app delegate from everywhere within the app, you can just call

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate someMethod];
```

Here, you can retrieve the folder you are interesting in with a public property declared in .h and synthesized in .m.

Now, this in not a so good approach to follow. AppDelegate class would remain as is.

Another, more elegant, approach is to create a singleton called `SharedManager` (or something else) that store the `currentFolder` that need to visualize.

Shared Manager will look like

```
//.h
@property (nonatomic,strong) Folder* currentFolder;

+ (SharedManager*)sharedInstance;


//.m
@synthesize currentFolder;

+ (SharedManager*)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[SharedManager alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

That, after importing it, it will be used to set a folder as the current one

```
[[SharedManager sharedInstance] setCurrentFolder:theFolderYouWantToShare];
```

or to retrieve the current folder

```
Folder* theSharedFolder = [[SharedManager sharedInstance] currentFolder];
```

P.S. Do not abuse on Singletons. The singleton pattern I use requires iOS 4 and greater.

**Edit 2**

It was my fault. I did not understand the question.

If you need to retrieve all the files, you could just create a `NSFetchRequest` like the following:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

NSError *error = nil; 
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

where `results` will contain all the files in your store **indipendently** from any folder. You can use this array to display files in your table.

If you have a lot of files, I really suggest to take a look at `NSFetchedResultsController` class. It allows lazy loading together with `UITableView`.

You can find a good tutorial here: [How To Use NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

**Edit 3**

> How to go about reminders?

You should provide to your request (the one you use with `NSFetchedResultsController`) a predicate like the following

```
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"reminder != nil"]];
```

In this manner you retrieve the files where reminder is NOT `nil`. `reminder` is the property you are using in the model.

P.S. Check the code because I've written without Xcode support.

Comment: Hello, thanks, for this , I have done this in my Master and detailViewController and everything works fine. Now to some files, I am setting reminders, to show local notifications. So whenever the notification pops up, their is delegate function for local notification, which should be written in appdelegate.m. Their I am creating an instance of this ThirdViewController and opening this ViewController to show files on that particular date and time. Hope this is clear. Now to pass these files to this thirdViewController.

Comment: @Ranjit I didn't understand your comment. Could you edit your question and provide details there? Thanks

Comment: Hi @flexaddicted,I dont want  to share folder, suppose I have two folders, folder1 and folder2, then I add file1 in folder1 and file2 in folder2, Now I have a view where I want to show all the files present , on tableView, irrespective of in whichever folder it is present. How to do that, and If I use singleton class, then again I have to save those entities some where , in plist. Hope you get it.

Comment: are you there? . I have a doubt