# Move rows to bottom in a TableView which uses CoreData

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, core-data, ios6

In my app  I have a folder-file (one-to-many relationship).So when I open my app, my firstViewController contains all files and when clicked on each folder, it opens a tableViewController displaying files in that folder.

Now here whenever I swipe any row, it is moved to bottom row and the table is update accordingly, the next swiped row will go and sit above the first swiped row.

Eg, at present if my table contains

```
0 1 2 3
A B C D
```

After swiping A

```
0 1 2   3
B C D **A**
```

after swiping B

```
0 1   2 3
C D **B A**
```

and so on,

To do this functionality, I should update the NSOrderedSet also
which is shown below

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.folder.file count]; i++)
        {
            File *file =  [self.folder.file objectAtIndex:i];
            if(file.completedStatus == false)
            {
                m_position = i;
                m_finalIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            }
        }

        file.completedStatus = YES;

        id obj = [self.folder. file objectAtIndex:row];

        NSMutableOrderedSet *files = [self.folder.file mutableCopy];
        [files removeObjectAtIndex:row];
        [files insertObject:obj atIndex:m_position];


        NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
        [m_tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:currentIndexPath toIndexPath:m_finalIndexPath];         
        self.folder.file = files;       
         }
         [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];    
         [m_tableView reloadData];
```

This works fine in this View, and here self.folder, is particular folder on which the user clicks

Now I have another ViewController called TestViewController where I have some of the file objects irrespective of in which ever folder they are present . I have populated the table of this TestViewController with these files, Now here also, when I swipe the cells, they will change the color but not move their position as above

Eg

```
0 1 2 3
A C B D

after swiping A and B

  0   1   2   3
**A** C **B** D
```

Now here A can belong to folder 1 and B can belong to folder 2,

when I close(dismiss) this TestViewController, What should happen is that

a) it shows me the fileViewController by default
b) the color of file A should change and it should move to a position by checking whether there are any swiped cells already. If yes, it should be placed above it or else at the bottom.

c) similarly for color B.

Regards
Ranjit.

Comment: If i get you right, then you are saying that you managed it on the firstView to move to the bottom? Why cant you do it on the moreView as well?

Comment: Hi @Andy,the moreView is a modelView, here I swipe a item , I have a property called swipe status to my file object, which I make it to true, when I swipe, and save the MOC and close the view, what I should do ahead, because, in firstView, I swipe and get the position of the row.

Comment: So, you need the position/cell where the swipe is executed on moreView?

Comment: This answers not my question from before. Do you need the position/cell/indexpath which needs to be moved on moreView?

Comment: Hey @Andy, are you there ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22236/discussion-between-ranjit-and-andy)

Comment: I read the edit. I really no idea to make this happens. The problem is quite specific. Maybe you could use a boolean property (that belongs to you file object) that can be checked when you return to the previous controller.

Comment: Did you got What I am trying to do

Comment: @flexaddicted, did you get my problem and can you please elaborate.

Comment: I understood your problem but it's quite difficult to provide a solution for this. I have no idea. Maybe create a bounty for the question. Other people could help you. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Ranjit,

About your question I cannot understand what you are asking here. So, please provide some other details.

To know the folder a specific file belongs to, this is quite simple to achieve.

If you have set up an inverse relationship between a file and a folder, simply access that relationship.

For example, if the inverse relationship is called `toFolder`, you can retrieve the current folder like

```
Folder* currentFolder = currentFile.toFolder; // or access it through KVC
```

To create an inverse relationship take a look here: [Core data structure use multiple entities or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072475/core-data-structure-use-multiple-entities-or-not/14072768#14072768)

Comment: Please tell me what you understood, so that I can explain you clearly further.

Comment: @Ranjit Could you show how do you update the ordered set? What do you mean with move to bottom the row? Thanks.

Comment: I solved my problem. Hurray :). But your answer of inverse relationship ave me a clue. I will provide the answer shortly

Comment: @Ranjit I'm happy to hear this. If you want upvote my answer ;-) Have a nice day.

Comment: where's the answer, @Ranjit?